# MASM assembly: How do I make a Procedure?

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2012, masm

I need to make a procedure that uses the built-in directive `invoke` instead of the instruction `call`.

So I need to know where I can place my prototype, my definition, and how I can call it?

Comment: I improved the question by highlighting some keywords and reformulating some grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to use proto and invoke with fast call (other than this is default for 64 bit mode). Example 32 bit flat model stand alone asm code using C library:

```
;       include C library
        if              @Version EQ 611 ;if ml 6.11
        includelib      libc
        else                            ;else ml 7.0 or later
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames
        endif

        .586p
        .model  flat,c
        .data           ;  initialized data
var1    dd      012345678h
var2    dd      087654321h
        .data?          ;uninitialized data
        .stack  4096
        .code

example proto   near c,arg1:dword,arg2:dword        

main    proc    near
        invoke  example,var1,var2
        xor     eax,eax
        ret
main    endp

;       argument names don't have to match proto
example proc    near c,a1:dword,a2:dword
        mov     eax,a1
        add     eax,a2
        ret
example endp

        end
```

Microsoft example with variable number of arguments (vararg):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/73407/using-proto-and-invoke-to-call-a-c-function-from-masm

Comment: somehow MS tends to obfuscate everything it finds, which assemblers do support this? i can imagine only MASM?

Comment: @Tommylee2k - invoke was added in Masm 6.0 (ml.exe), along with other stuff like the "dot" directives such as .if / .else / .endif / .while / .continue / .break ... [masm directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx) . I'm not aware of any other assemblers that support this.

Comment: what is near c??

Comment: @Advancedip - `near` means it's a near (versus far) call, with a flat model, all normal calls would be near. `c` is the language type, in which case any public symbols to be used by the linker will have a underscore prefix, so `main` would show up as `_main` to the linker. See [Masm guide.pdf](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf)